# Error handling in global.asax MVC 3.0 problem on server 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling, windows-server-2008

I created

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState)
   {
      try
      {
         var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
         Exception exception = httpContext.Server.GetLastError();

         if (exception is HttpRequestValidationException)
         {
            httpContext.Response.Clear();
            var logLoggerService = new LogLoggerService();
            logLoggerService.Error("ValidationException", exception);
            WriteErrorResponse(exception.Message);
         }
         else
         {
            httpContext.Response.Clear();
            var logLoggerService = new LogLoggerService();

            logLoggerService.Error(exception);
            WriteErrorResponse(exception.Message);
         }
     }
     catch
     {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        httpContext.Response.Clear();
     }
  }
}
```

I found that when error occurred on server, this function is not call. But when I am in debug mode, the `Application_Error` is called.

Why this does not work on server? Maybe problem with IIS or with .NET 4.0 on server?

On server I have:

Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 15-8-2011 8:25:26 
Event time (UTC): 15-8-2011 6:25:26 
Event ID: ae3cad590adc43c3803410023cccb6b0 
Event sequence: 4 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/11/ROOT-1-129578631124796958 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestnaAplikacijaZaLog\ 
    Machine name: SRJ1-SRV-01

Process information: 
    Process ID: 6644 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\TestnaAplikacijaZaLog

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Response is not available in this context.
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)

Response is not available in this context.
   at System.Web.HttpContext.get_Response()
   at LogiranjeGresaka.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\users\esmira\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\LogiranjeGresaka\LogiranjeGresaka\Global.asax.cs:line 46

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://192.168.0.100:2227/Home/Index 
    Request path: /Home/Index 
    User host address: 192.168.0.103 
    User:
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\TestnaAplikacijaZaLog

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 7 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\TestnaAplikacijaZaLog 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)

Custom event details:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve problem with adding

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is being called, but the error is being thrown by the code above as detailed by the error message:

> > Exception information: Exception type: HttpException 
> >     Exception message: Response is not available in this context

You are trying to use Response, but you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Right here, it is telling you the line number where the problem is:

Response is not available in this context. at System.Web.HttpContext.get_Response() at LogiranjeGresaka.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\users\esmira\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\LogiranjeGresaka\LogiranjeGresaka\Global.asax.cs:**line 46**

Line 46
Global.asax